# How to write on an image XAML control?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to make credit card input system for my Xamarin.Forms App.
I would like to enter a credit card number on a credit card image but I cannot figure out how to do so.

I would like to use XAML to write on the card like the gif below.
any help would be appreciated!

[image: I would like to do something like this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overlap a label on your credit card image:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <Image Source="cardImage.png"
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 150, 150"/>
  <Label Text="Credit card number here"
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.8, 1, 1"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: And then to use a Reference Bind between the label text and the entry text. That's it.